# 3D graph out of two 2D graphs

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, economics, mixing-variables

I have the following two graphs:

$$f(x)=(43700 - x)/2$$
$$g(y)=-16150 + 100 y - 2 (-19000 + 100 y)$$

The functions $f$ and $g$ show the liquidation price of a margin trading position for a commodity with price $x$ (with the single underlying collateral in the commodity with price $x$ or with price $y$). So that when the price of the commodity goes down, the liquidation price of the position goes up.

I would like to build a 3D graph of the liquidation price $z(x,y)$, when a single commodity $x$ has underlying collateral in both the commodity with price $x$ and the commodity with price $y$. This happens when a margin trading position is open for commodity $X$, but has underlying commodities $X$ and $Y$ as the collateral. Thus the liquidation price depends on both $x$ and $y$, and not just on either one of them.

Of course, simply combining $f$ and $g$ in the fashion $z=f+g$ won't work, since the liquidation price depends on the price of two collateral commodities, $x$ and $y$, but the trading position is denominated in just the commodity $x$.

**Long story short**, how does one build the graph of the function which is similar to $f(x)$, but also depends on $y$ as in $g(y)$? The idea is to combine the variables $x$ and $y$ in the two functions to make a single 3D graph dependent on both variables.

Comment: I think it's your "of course" paragraph that matters.  You really need to know exactly how these quantities interact before you can build your desired function. Vaguely, "how much more" does $x$ matter than $y$?

Comment: @Randall I know how $f$ (the liquidation price) behaves when $X$ is in the trading position and the collateral is also in $X$. I also know how $g$ (the liquidation price of $X$) behaves when the trading position is in $X$ but the collateral is in $Y$. So that's the idea - to build a function which shows the liquidation price of $X$ with collateral in both $X$ and $Y$. This was thought of as a relatively simple/trivial problem, but turns out this is not very much the case.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ completely independent?  (Or, you could just wait until someone who actually knows something about this topic drops in.)

Comment: @Randall They are independent.

Comment: Then I would be inclined to believe in Bailey's answer.  There must be some important context I'm missing.  Again, someone helpful will be by in a bit!

Comment: If we multiply $f$ and $g$ then the problem hides somewhere in the translation terms $43700/2$ in $f(x)$ and the ones in $g(y)$. These translation terms work well for $f$ and $g$ as separate functions, but not in the case of the product $fg$. The translation terms in the separate cases determine the price of the commodity at the time the position is open.